# what is the difference between Observable and a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

As per my understanding both Observable.create and a normal javascript function are look similar to me . So what is the actual difference between both?

```
var observable= Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
  observer.next("Hello World");
});
observable.subscribe(function (x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

**Normal function**

```
function myfunction() {
  console.log('Hello World');

}

myfunction();
```

Comment: Here's a hint as to why the Observable is important: how do you return the value from an asynchronous function? What if you want to be notified when another piece of code calls the function? What if you have a function called by `setInterval` and you want to somehow combine the result with another function that runs in a different interval? That may sound contrived but that sort of thing happens all the time in gamedev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As per my understanding both Observable.create and a normal javascript function are look similar to me . So what is the actual difference between both?

They are both just functions. Observables can seem like dark magic but it comes down to Javascript objects and functions.

Basically, first we need an `observer`. This is just an object with three properties:

```
{
  //a function to be executed when we want the Observable to emit. Takes 1 arg
  next:     (val) : void

  //a func to be executed when an uncaught exception occurs. Takes 1 arg
  error:    (err) : void

  //a func to be executed when we want the Observable to stop. Takes no arg
  complete: () : void
}
```

Now consider the signature of `Observable.create`

```
Observable.create(
  function(observer)
) : Observable {}
```

So to create an observable, we pass it a reference to a function.  This function is not executed right away, but it will be executed when we call `.subscribe()` on the Observable that `create()` returned.

To make sense of it, suppose we wanted to create an observable that emits the new value of a text input every time it changes.

```
let obs = Observable.create(observer=>{
  let input = document.querySelector('#myInput');
  input.onchange = (event) => {
     let newVal = event.target.value;
     if(newVal == 'stop') observer.complete();
     else observer.next(event.target.value);
   }
});
```

All we have at this point is an object `obs` that is storing a function that will be executed when we call subscribe. Since this function expects a parameter that respects the `observer` interface, it makes sense that `subscribe` takes 3 parameters. When we're ready to start listening for value changes:

```
obs.subscribe(
  // this is the function that will be called from within the Observable
  // when the value changes. Behind the scenes this function is just
  // assigned to observer.next
  newVal => {console.log(newVal)},

  error => {}, // assigned to observer.error

  () => {}     // assigned to observer.complete. Executed if new val is 'stop'
)
```

Now you see how, each time the `onchange` event is raised on the input, `observer.next(newVal)` is called, which is just another name for the first argument of `.subscribe()`!

In my opinion, what makes Observable awesome is how they can be chained, or composed. Maybe I'm not interested in learning about all value changes, but only those that have a length greater than 3. Easy. Instead of subscribing to the original `obs`, I apply the `.filter()` operator:

```
obs.filter(newVal => newVal.length > 3).subscribe('...')
```

Notice that what was passed is a function. The end result will be that only the outputs that pass the filter will reach `.subscribe()`.  How is that done? Something like this:

```
class Observable {
  filter: (filterFunc) {
    // create a new observable. This is now what your code will subscribe to.
    // the original observable is now upstream, and accessed below
    return Observable.create( observer => {
      // subscribe to the original observable so we can see input value changes
      this.subscribe(
        // pass on the value only if it makes it through the filter
        newVal => {if(filterFunc(newVal)) observer.next(newVal)},
        // errors flow downstream
        error  => observer.error(error),
        // Stop immediately if the upstream observable completes
        complete => observer.complete()
      );
    } )
  }
}
```

Again, nothing magical. the `.filter()` operator created a new observable that subscribed to the original observable. When the original emits,the new receives the value and manipulates it in a way before passing its own result to its observer.  So when you do `obs.filter(filterFunc).subscribe()`, you're receiving the output of the 2nd observer. It's the number and [flexibility of these operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/create.html) paired with the *notify-me-when* design paradigm that make Observables so powerful.

I recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LKMwkuK0ZE) by the architect of RxJS 5. If you only have a few minutes, [look at this post](https://medium.com/@benlesh/learning-observable-by-building-observable-d5da57405d87) by the same architect.

Comment: Your explanation is pretty clear for me ..thanks.. One more question is this asynchronous by default??

Comment: @JEMI no. It all depends on the work the Observable is asked to do. For instance `Observable.of(5)` is synchronous (if you subscribe, you get results immediately), but `Observable.interval(5000)` will not output anything for 5 seconds.  Observables make asynchronous code easier to write though because inside `subscribe` you can be sure that the work is done.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to think about it is that a function has a start and an end. You call it, it does something, and then ends. Obviously there are exceptions, but for the purpose of this conversation that explanation should be fine.

An observable on the other hand is best thought of as a "window" through which to view a stream of data, and instructions on how to react when new data is "seen" through the window. Another distinction to be made between a function and an observable is that a function, most likely, is dealing with static data, whereas an Observable is dealing with a stream. So there is a time component to observables which is where a lot of the confusion comes into play. Functions typically take a snapshot of data and operate on it. Observables look at data over time and have instructions on how to react to it.

Lets take the example below to illustrate how Observables are so powerful in modern day programming. Let's assume we have a `Users` object (static data) for the "Function Approach" and a `UsersData` observable (stream of data over time), both of which carry the data for the users within our application. We want to display all of the users registered in our application.

**FUNCTION APPROACH**

```
function getUsers() {
    return Users;
}

getUsers();
```

This approach will return all of the users when it's called. Likely when the page loads and the model is instantiated. Turning it into static data once the page has loaded.

**OBSERVABLE APPROACH**

```
function getUsers() {
    UserDataObservable.subscribe(_Users => {
        this.Users = _Users
    }
}

getUsers();
```

The observable approach `subscribes` to the `UserData` observable allowing us to push new data to the observable which in turn updates the model's `Users` property, which in turn updates the view. In other words it not only grabs a snapshot of the data initially, but it also opens a window into the data so new data can be observed and reacted to.

So to circle back to your original question your function would be done once you called it, whereas you could keep pushing strings to your observable and they would keep being logged to the console.

Answer (score 1):

I also got some good explanation from their official documentation

**Observables can "return" multiple values over time**, something which functions cannot. You can't do this:

```
function foo() {
  console.log('Hello');
  return 42;
  return 100; // dead code. will never happen
}
```

Functions can only return one value. Observables, however, can do this:

```
var foo = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
  console.log('Hello');
  observer.next(42);
  observer.next(100); // "return" another value
  observer.next(200); // "return" yet another
});

console.log('before');
foo.subscribe(function (x) {
  console.log(x);
});
console.log('after');
```

**Conclusion:**

- func.call() means "*give me one value synchronously*"
- observable.subscribe() means "*give me any amount of values, either
  synchronously or asynchronously*"

Answer (score 0):

An observable is an object/entity which operates on **discrete** or **continuous** sequence of information. Example for discrete set of information is elements in an Array and for continuous information you can consider any event. And subscriber is some guy/function who needs those information which is implicitly called/given by the observer every time.

> Take YouTube bell as example. YouTube will notify updates of
>   channel for which you subscribed and pressed bell icon. No matter you are interested in that update or not.

But function is explicit it works only when you call it.

> Like how you visit a channel in YouTube and watch video. Based on you interest you may watch some video but not all.

.